# Llamar una, dos o más funciones dentro de otra función en Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, método

Con la explicación que me dieron en una de las preguntas anteriores sobre como entender y cambar la sintaxis desde MATLAB a Pyhton, he solucionado parcialmente el problema que tenía. Ahora mi duda radica en que dentro de una de las funciones debo declarar algunas variables que depende de otra función.

¿Cómo debería ser la forma adecuada para llamar una función dentro de otra?

Les anexo el código que tengo:

```
#Parametros
#Instantes de tiempo para simular
import numpy as np
from math import exp,ceil
#----------------------------------------
tvec=np.insert(np.arange(0,10,0.1),len(np.arange(0,10,0.1)),10).transpose()
st0=np.array([1,1,0,0])*0.6
b=2*np.ones((2, 1))
#----------------------------------------
#Creacion de la función optimal_cntrl_calc_var_nsec_odesol
def optimal_cntrl_calc_var_nsec_odesol(tvec,st0,b):
    # Esta función calcula el control óptimo y
    # los estados correspondientes y los co-estados.
    # Método de descenso más pronunciado se utiliza para esto.
    # n = N°. de secciones
    nt=len(tvec)
    n=len(st0)
    n=n/2
    utim=0.1*np.ones((int(nt),int(n))) #asume la integración de
    #control de avance para los estados
    stmat=fwdstinteg(tvec,utim,st0,b)#VARIABLE QUE DEPENDE DE UNA FUNCIÓN
    rho=stmat[:,0:n+1]
    rhof=rho[end,:]
    #tiempo de incremento para la simulación
    dt=tvec[1]-tvec[0]
    #funcion de costo para la simulación
    #axis=1 => horizontal
    #axis=0 => vertical
    J=np.sum(np.sum(rho**2 + utim**2,axis=1)*dt)+np.sum(rhof**2)
    #itera= número de iteraciones de actualización de control
    #Jiter= vector de valores de costo de iteración
    itera=1
    Jiter[itera]=J
    #convergencia
    #test=0 => no ocurre test=1 => ocurre
    test=0
    #Tolerancias
    tol=10**(-4)
    tol2=10**(-6)
    #iteraciones para control y costo hasta
    #que ocurre la convergencia
    while (test==0):#para chequear la convergencia
        itera=itera+1
        stf=(stmat[-1:,]).transpose()
        rhof=stf[0:n+1]
        v=[[[2*rhof]],np.zeros(n)]
        costf=np.array(v)
        #integración hacia atrás para co-estados
        costmat=bkcostinteg(tvec,stmat,costf,b) #VARIABLE QUE DEPENDE DE OTRA FUNCION
        #calculo dhdu de todo el tiempo
        dhdu=2*utim+costmat[:,n+2:2*(n+1)]
        #"cntrl_update" actualiza el control y el estado
        #para la próxima iteración
        metod2=cntrl_update(tvec,stmat,utim,dhdu,b,tol,tol2) #VARIABLE QUE DEPENDE DE OTRA FUNCION
        Jiter[iter]=J
    rho=stmat[:,0:n+1]
    vf=stmat[:,n+2:2*(n+1)]
    p=costmat[:,0:n+1]
    pvf=costmat[:,n+2:2*(n+1)]
    #cálculo del hamiltoniano
    H=np.zeros(int(nt))
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        H=H+rho[:,i]**2 + utim[:,i]**2 +p[:,i]*(-rho[:,i]*(1-rho[:,i])*b[i]*vf[:,i])
        H=H+pvf[:,i]*utim[:,i]
        if i>=2:
            H=H+p[:,i]*(rho[:,i-1]*(1-rho[:,i-1])*b[i]*vf[:,i-1])

    return stmat,utim,costmat,dhdu,Jiter,H

def cntrl_update(tvec,stmat,utim,dhdu,b,tol1,tol2):
    test=0
    dt=tvec(2)-tvec(1)
    nsi=stmat.shape
    # n=N° of sections, st0=initial states
    n=nsi(2)
    n=n/2
    st0=stmat[0,:].transpose()
    rho=stmat[:,1:n]
    rhof=rho[-1,:]#end=-1
    # norm of dhdu
    nordhdu=math.sqrt(np.sum(np.sum(dhdu**2,axis=0)*dt)) 
    # cost for current control
    J=np.sum(np.sum(rho**2+utim**2,axis=0)*dt)+np.sum(rhof**2)
    # norm check for convergence
    if nordhdu <= tol:
        test=1 
        print(['nordhdu=',str(nordhdu)]) ;
    #J1= some qty set > J. will be used in the
    # iteration below to assign the updated cost
    J1=J+1 ;
    # step taken in terms of the maximum value of utim
    tau=0.1*max(max(abs(utim)))
    # control update procedure:
    while J1>=J :
        # control update
        utim1=utim-tau*dhdu
        # state update
        stmat=fwdstinteg(tvec,utim1,st0,b)
        # rho and rhof extracted
        rho=stmat[:,0:n+1]; rhof=rho[-1,:]#end=-1
        # J1=new cost
        J1=np.sum(np.sum(rho**2+utim1**2,axis=0)*dt)+np.sum(rhof**2)
        # adjustment in the step size
        tau=tau/2
    # updated control and cost
    utim=utim1
    if abs(J1-J) <= tol2:
        test=1 
        print(['abs(J1-J) =',str(abs(J1-J))])
    J=J1
    return stmat,utim,J,test

#-------------------------
def fwdstinteg(tvec,utim,st0,b):
    ## This routine performs the forward integration
    ## of the state equations using the euler step
    ## method.
    nt=len(tvec) #length of the time vector
    st=st0 
    dt=tvec[1]-tvec[0] 
    #iterative procedure for the simulation
    #for it=1:1:(nt-1):
    for it in range(1,int(nt)):
        stmat[it,:]=st.transpose() 
        u=utim[it,:] 
        # time derivative of the states
        stdot=stdyn(st,b,u) 
        # euler step method to compute the
        # state at next time instant
        st=st+stdot*dt        
    stmat[int(nt),:]=st
    return stmat

def stdyn(st,b,u):
    # This routine performs the backward integration
    # of the state equations using the euler step
    # method.
    n=len(st)/2 # number of sections
    rho=st[0:n+1] 
    vf=st[n+2:2*(n+1)] 
    rd[0,0]=-rho[0]*(1-rho[0])*b[0]*vf[0] 
    rd[1:n+1,0]=rho[0:n,0]*(1-rho[0:n,0])*b[1:n+1]*vf[0:n,0]-rho[1:n+1,0]*(1-rho[1:n+1,0])*b[1:n+1]*vf[1:n+1,0] 
    vfd[0:n+1,0]=u 
    stdot=[rd,vfd] 
    return stdot

def bkcostinteg(tvec,stmat,costf,b):
    # This routine computes the time derivative
    # of the co-state equations
    nt=len(tvec) #length of the time vector
    cost=costf
    dt=tvec[1]-tvec[0]
    for it in range(int(nt)+1,0,-1):
        costmat[it,:]=cost.transpose()
        st=stmat[it,:].transpose()
        costdot=costdyn[cost,b,st]
        cost=cost-costdot*dt
        costmat[0,:]=cost
    return costmat

def costdyn(cost,b,st):
    # This routine computes the time
    # derivative of the co-state vector
    n=len(cost)/2 # N° of sections
    rho=st[0:n+1]
    vf=st[n+2:2*(n+1)]
    p=cost[0:n+1]
    pv=cost[n+2:2*(n+1)]
    pd[0:n,0]=-(2*rho[0:n,0]+p[0:n,0]*((-1+2*rho[0:n,0])*b[0:n]*vf[0:n])+p[1:n+1]*((1-2*rho[0:n])*b[1:n+1]*vf[0:n])) 
    pd[n+1,0]=-(2*rho[n]+p[n]*((-1+2*rho[n])*b[n]*vf[n])) 
    pvd[0:n,0]=-(p[0:n]*(-rho[0:n]*(1-rho[0:n])*b[0:n])+p[1:n+1]*(rho[0:n]*(1-rho[0:n])*b[1:n+1]))
    pvd[n+1,0]=-(p[n+1]*(-rho[n+1]*(1-rho[n+1])*b[n+1])) 
    costdot=[pd,pvd]
    return costdot

#-----------------------------MAIN----------------------------------


#Llamado de la routina de contro, optimal
#rho=ped. densities, vf=free flow velocities
res=optimal_cntrl_calc_var_nsec_odesol(tvec,st0,b)
```

Al momento de ejecutar me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\OptimalTimesExamples.py", line 182, in <module>
    res=optimal_cntrl_calc_var_nsec_odesol(tvec,st0,b)
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\OptimalTimesExamples.py", line 21, in optimal_cntrl_calc_var_nsec_odesol
    stmat=fwdstinteg(tvec,utim,st0,b)
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\OptimalTimesExamples.py", line 124, in fwdstinteg
    stmat[it,:]=st.transpose()
NameError: name 'stmat' is not defined
```

CÓDIGO DE MATLAB:

MAIN:

```
% Setting up the parameters
%time instants for simulation
tvec=(0:0.1:10)';
st0=[1;1;0;0]*0.6; % initial state
b=2*ones(2,1); % b values
% Calling the optimal control routine
[stmat,utim,costmat,dhdu,Jiter,H]...
=optimal_cntrl_calc_var_nsec_odesol...
(tvec,st0,b) ;
% Plotting the results
% rho=ped. densities, vf= free flow
% velocities
rho=stmat(:,1:2) ; vf=stmat(:,3:4) ;
% plot of (u_1,u_2) v/s time
figure ;
hp=plot(tvec,utim(:,1),'k-',...
tvec,utim(:,2),'k--');
set(hp,'LineWidth',2) ;
h=legend('u_1','u_2');
set(h,'FontSize',16) ;
xlabel('t(s)','FontSize',16) ;
ylabel('u_i','FontSize',16) ;
% plot of (rho_1,rho_2) v/s time
figure ;
hp=plot(tvec,stmat(:,1),'k-',...
tvec,stmat(:,2),'k--');
set(hp,'LineWidth',2) ;
h=legend('\rho_1','\rho_2');
set(h,'FontSize',16) ;
xlabel('t(s)','FontSize',16) ;
ylabel('\rho_i','FontSize',16) ;
% plot of (vf_1,vf_2) v/s time
figure ;
hp=plot(tvec,stmat(:,3),'k-',...
tvec,stmat(:,4),'k--');
set(hp,'LineWidth',2) ;
h=legend('v_{f_1}','v_{f_2}');
set(h,'FontSize',16) ;
xlabel('t(s)','FontSize',16) ;
ylabel('vf_i','FontSize',16) ;
% plot of (p_1,p_2) v/s time
figure;
hp=plot(tvec,costmat(:,1),...
'k-',tvec,costmat(:,2),'k--');
set(hp,'LineWidth',2);
h=legend('p_1','p_2');
set(h,'FontSize',16) ;
xlabel('t(s)','FontSize',16) ;
ylabel('p_i','FontSize',16) ;
% plot of (p_vf1,p_vf2) v/s time
figure ;
hp=plot(tvec,costmat(:,3),'k-'...
,tvec,costmat(:,4),'k--');
set(hp,'LineWidth',2);
h=legend('p_{vf1}','p_{vf2}');
set(h,'FontSize',16) ;
xlabel('t(s)','FontSize',16) ;
ylabel('p_{vf_i}','FontSize',16)
% plot of (dh/du_1,dh/du_2) v/s
% time
figure ;
hp=plot(tvec,dhdu(:,1),'k-',...
tvec,dhdu(:,2),'k--') ;
set(hp,'LineWidth',2);
h=legend('{\partial H}/{\partial u_1}'...
,'{\partial H}/{\partial u_2}') ;
set(h,'FontSize',16) ;
xlabel('t(s)','FontSize',16) ;
ylabel('{\partial H}/{\partial u_i}'...
,'FontSize',16) ;
% plot of hamiltonian v/s time
figure ;
plot(tvec,H) ; legend('H') ;
```

MÉTODOS:

```
function [stmat,utim,costmat,dhdu,Jiter,H]...
=optimal_cntrl_calc_var_nsec_odesol(tvec,st0,b)
% This function computes the optimal control and
% the corresponding states and the co-states.
% Method of Steepest Descent is used for this.
% n=no. of sections
nt=length(tvec) ; n=length(st0) ; n=n/2 ;
utim=0.1*ones(nt,n) ; % assume control
% forward integration for states
stmat=fwdstinteg(tvec,utim,st0,b) ;
rho=stmat(:,1:n); rhof=rho(end,:);
% time increment for simulation
dt=tvec(2)-tvec(1) ;
% cost function for the simulation
J=sum(sum(rho.^2+utim.^2,2)*dt)+sum(rhof.^2);
% iter=no of control update iterations
% Jiter=vector of iteration cost values
iter=1 ; Jiter(iter)=J ;
% convergence:
% test=0 => not occured test=1 => occured.
test=0 ;
% tolerences
tol1=10^-4 ; tol2=10^-6 ;
% iterations for control and cost till
% convergence occurs
while test==0 % check for convergence
iter=iter+1 ;
stf=stmat(end,:)’ ; rhof=stf(1:n) ;
costf=[2*rhof;zeros(n,1)] ;
% backward integration for co-states
costmat=bkcostinteg(tvec,stmat,costf,b) ;
% calculation dhdu at all time
dhdu=2*utim+costmat(:,n+1:2*n) ;
% "cntrl_update" updates the control and state
% for the next iteration
[stmat,utim,J,test]=...
cntrl_update(tvec,stmat,utim,dhdu,b,tol1,tol2) ;
% Jiter(iter)=value of the cost function at the
% current iteration.
Jiter(iter)=J ;
end
rho=stmat(:,1:n) ; vf=stmat(:,n+1:2*n) ;
p=costmat(:,1:n) ; pvf=costmat(:,n+1:2*n) ;
% Computation for hamiltonian
H=zeros(nt,1) ;
for i=1:1:n
H=H+rho(:,i).^2+utim(:,i).^2+p(:,i)...
.*(-rho(:,i).*(1-rho(:,i))*b(i).*vf(:,i)) ;
H=H+pvf(:,i).*utim(:,i) ;
if i>=2
H=H+p(:,i).*(rho(:,i-1).*(1-rho(:,i-1))...
*b(i).*vf(:,i-1)) ;
end
end
end
function [stmat,utim,J,test]=...
cntrl_update(tvec,stmat,utim,dhdu,b,tol1,tol2)
test=0 ;
dt=tvec(2)-tvec(1); nsi=size(stmat);
% n=no of sections, st0=initial states
n=nsi(2); n=n/2; st0=stmat(1,:)’;
rho=stmat(:,1:n); rhof=rho(end,:);
% norm of dhdu
nordhdu=sqrt(sum(sum(dhdu.^2,2)*dt)) ;
% cost for current control
J=sum(sum(rho.^2+utim.^2,2)*dt)...
+sum(rhof.^2);
% norm check for convergence
if nordhdu <= tol1
test=1 ;
disp([’nordhdu=’,num2str(nordhdu)]) ;
return ;
end
% J1= some qty set > J. will be used in the
% iteration below to assign the updated cost
J1=J+1 ;
% step taken in terms of the maximum value of utim
tau=0.1*max(max(abs(utim))) ;
% control update procedure:
while J1>=J
% control update
utim1=utim-tau*dhdu ;
% state update
stmat=fwdstinteg(tvec,utim1,st0,b) ;
% rho and rhof extracted
rho=stmat(:,1:n); rhof=rho(end,:);
% J1=new cost
J1=sum(sum(rho.^2+utim1.^2,2)*dt)...
+sum(rhof.^2) ;
% adjustment in the step size
tau=tau/2 ;
end
% updated control and cost
utim=utim1 ;
if abs(J1-J) <= tol2
test=1 ;
disp([’abs(J1-J) =’,num2str(abs(J1-J))]) ;
end
J=J1 ;
end
function stmat=fwdstinteg(tvec,utim,st0,b)
% This routine performs the forward integration
% of the state equations using the euler step
% method.
nt=length(tvec) ; % length of the time vector
st=st0 ;
dt=tvec(2)-tvec(1) ;
% iterative procedure for the simulation
for it=1:1:(nt-1)
stmat(it,:)=st’ ;
u=utim(it,:) ;
% time derivative of the states
stdot=stdyn(st,b,u) ;
% euler step method to compute the
% state at next time instant
st=st+stdot*dt ;
end
stmat(nt,:)=st ;
end
function stdot=stdyn(st,b,u)
% This routine performs the backward integration
% of the state equations using the euler step
% method.
n=length(st)/2 ; % number of sections
rho=st(1:n) ; vf=st(n+1:2*n) ;
rd(1,1)=-rho(1)*(1-rho(1))*b(1)*vf(1) ;
rd(2:n,1)=rho(1:n-1,1).*(1-rho(1:n-1,1))...
.*b(2:n).*vf(1:n-1,1)-rho(2:n,1)...
.*(1-rho(2:n,1)).*b(2:n).*vf(2:n,1) ;
vfd(1:n,1)=u ;
stdot=[rd;vfd] ;
return
end
function costmat=bkcostinteg(tvec,...
stmat,costf,b)
% This routine computes the time derivative
% of the co-state equations
nt=length(tvec) ; % length of the time vector
cost=costf ;
dt=tvec(2)-tvec(1) ;
for it=nt:-1:2
costmat(it,:)=cost’ ;
st=stmat(it,:)’ ;
costdot=costdyn(cost,b,st) ;
cost=cost-costdot*dt ;
end
costmat(1,:)=cost ;
end
function costdot=costdyn...
(cost,b,st)
% This routine computes the time
% derivative of the co-state vector
n=length(cost)/2 ; % no of sections
rho=st(1:n); vf=st(n+1:2*n);
p=cost(1:n); pv=cost(n+1:2*n);
pd(1:n-1,1)=-(2*rho(1:n-1,1)...
+p(1:n-1,1).*((-1+2*rho(1:n-1,1))...
.*b(1:n-1).*vf(1:n-1))+p(2:n)...
.*((1-2*rho(1:n-1)).*b(2:n).*vf(1:n-1))) ;
pd(n,1)=-(2*rho(n)+p(n)*...
((-1+2*rho(n))*b(n)*vf(n))) ;
pvd(1:n-1,1)=-(p(1:n-1).*(-rho(1:n-1)...
.*(1-rho(1:n-1)).*b(1:n-1))...
+p(2:n).*(rho(1:n-1).*(1-rho(1:n-1))...
.*b(2:n))) ;
pvd(n,1)=-(p(n)*(-rho(n)*(1-rho(n))*b(n))) ;
costdot=[pd;pvd] ;
end
```

Comment: Hola Alex, el problema no es llamar una función desde otra, el error se debe a que dentro de tu función `fwdstinteg` intentas hacer un indexado con `stmat[it,:]` cuando dentro de  `fwdstinteg` la variable `stmat` no existe porque no la has declarado en ningún momento ni es recibida como parámetro. ¿De dónde se supone que viene `stmat` cuando intentas usarla dentro de `fwdstinteg` ?

Comment: He revisado el código hecho en MATLAB y en ninguna parte parece stmat "declarado". Y por eso tenía la duda, ya que en MATLAB si funciona dicho programa.

Comment: Vale, en ese caso la matriz se está creando en el propio for, esto no es igual en NumPy dado que los arrays tienen unas dimensiones estáticas para primar el rendimiento, recuerda además que el indexado empieza por 0.  Lo normal es crear un array de ceros con las dimensiones requeridas y luego modificarlo. Alex sería de gran ayuda que proporcionaras el código de MATLAB de la función `fwdstinteg` y `stdyn` junto a unos valores ejemplo de los argumentos `tvec`,`utim`,`st0` y `b` para usarlos con la función. Esto nos permitiría reproducir el código y facilitaría mucho dar una respuesta.

Comment: Ok, yo te anexo el código de MATLAB